# How to suppress printing "0" in vim when using skeleton/eval dynamic templates

Tags: vim

When I load a template with a function with no explicitly specified return value in the template's placeholder-eval block, Vim executes the function but also types "0" instead of the placeholder. The "0" is a function's exit code I assume.

I'd like to suppress printing of "0".

This is in my `.vimrc`:

```
augroup templates
  au!
  " read in template files
  autocmd BufNewFile *.* silent! execute '0r $HOME/.vim/templates/skeleton.'.expand("<afile>:e")

  " parse special text in the templates after the read
  autocmd BufNewFile * %s#\[:VIM_EVAL:\]\(.\{-\}\)\[:END_EVAL:\]#\=eval(submatch(1))#ge
augroup END
```

When I create a file with an extension for which I've got a skeleton file in my ~/.vim/templates directory, Vim reads the content of the template file in a buffer and substitutes the contents of `[:VIM_EVAL:]` "tags" or "placeholders" by evaluating it with `eval()`. If the placeholder is a function with no return value specified, like `cursor(100,1)` below, Vim will type "0" in place of this `VIM_EVAL` placeholder. How do I avoid such behavior?

My template file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#[:VIM_EVAL:]MyCoolFunctionWithReturnValue()[:END_EVAL:] #this function works as I expect
use strict;
use warnings;
[:VIM_EVAL:]cursor(100,1)[:END_EVAL:] # this built-in vim function movers the cursor but also types "0" digit on the line before the cursor.
```

Comment: You could remove the zeros by modifying the auto command to: `autocmd BufNewFile * %s#...#\=eval...#ge | %s/^0$//`

Comment: That's just great! I didn't know that we can pipe output with (|) in vim. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ivan not a pipe; command separator. Simpler to check the results of the eval, imo—that sub might delete things you dont want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not because `cursor()` doesn't return any value, but actually because `cursor()` will return 0 for success and -1 for failure.

From [`:help cursor()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#cursor%28%29):

> Returns 0 when the position could be set, -1 otherwise.

So one possible solution is to wrap that into a function that returns an empty string instead.

```
function! MoveCursor(lnum, col)
    call cursor(a:lnum, a:col)
    return ''
endfunction
```

And then refer to that function in your template:

```
[:VIM_EVAL:]MoveCursor(100,1)[:END_EVAL:]
```

An alternative that doesn't involve creating a wrapper function is to use an expression that will call the function you want, but still evaluate to an empty string. Examples are:

```
[:VIM_EVAL:]cursor(100,1) ? '' : ''[:END_EVAL:]
```

Or:

```
[:VIM_EVAL:][cursor(100,1), ''][-1][:END_EVAL:]
```

The first uses the `? :` operator to define what to return depending on whether the expression is true or false. But in this case we return an empty string either way.

The second creates an array (so it evaluates every expression for each element) and then pick the last element, which is an empty string.

Either of these should work well for your particular use case.